# Matplotlib import issue across modules

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, data-visualization

I am making a data visualization project that takes input data from a file and outputs a set of figures. Let's sat I have 3 different modules each with matplotlib imported and I use then in the main.py file as

```
# main.py file
from wc import make_wordcloud
from weekday_vis import make_week_vis
from chat_activity import timeline

print("Creating WordCloud ...")
make_wordcloud()

print("Creating weekday visualization ...")
weekday_vis.make_week_vis()

print("Creating Timeline ...")
timeline()
```

The images produced by them worked fine when I was testing each module individually but when I put them into main.py basically everything messed up.

This is the code in my word cloud file

```
def make_wc_figure():
    #text processing code omitted
    
    wordcloud = WordCloud(width=2000, height=1000).generate(with_string)
    plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10), facecolor='k')
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
    plt.savefig("output/wordcloud.png")
```

This is in weekday_vis

```
def make_figure():
    #data processing code omitted
    week_chart = sns.barplot(df_day.index, df_day.values, alpha=0.8, palette='rocket', order=order)
    week_chart.set(xlabel='Weekdays', ylabel='Messages')
    plt.savefig("output/week_vis.png")
```

And this in chat activity

```
def timeline():
    #data processing code omitted
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    sns.set_context("paper")
    chart = sns.barplot(final_data["Date"], final_data["Messages"], alpha=1, palette='husl', data=final_data)
    chart.set(xlabel='Timeline', ylabel='Messages')
    chart.set_xticklabels(final_labels, rotation=90, fontweight='light', horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=6)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("output/timeline.png")
```

I believe this is because of the plt import but can't figure out how to rectify it. Is there any way how I can make this work? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new `figure` for each plot by passing different integers.

For example,

```
print("Creating WordCloud ...")
make_wordcloud(1)

print("Creating weekday visualization ...")
weekday_vis.make_week_vis(2)

print("Creating Timeline ...")
timeline(3)
```

Then, you need to use the integer in your functions to create different plots.

```
def make_wc_figure(p_num):
    ...
    plt.figure(num=p_num, figsize=(20, 10), facecolor='k')
    ...

def make_figure(p_num):
    ...
    plt.figure(num=p_num)
    ...

def timeline(p_num):
    ...
    plt.figure(num=p_num, figsize=(20, 10))
    ...
```

As you can see, this is kind of quick and dirty fix of your issue. If you just want to do this once, then just simply do it like this. However, it is recommended to use object-oriented approach to refactor your code.

Comment: Thank you this lil hack worked! What I had to do was to add the plt.figure() thing before every figure was generated. I'll refactor the code to make it object-oriented too. Thanks!